# Errors With Method Filter JS - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, filter

Because I get this error when executing the filter method

This a code -->

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nczYR.png)

Comment: please add the error and data set (a small one).

Comment: What is the error? What environment are you running this in? (For instance: No version of IE supports arrow functions.)

Comment: For the future, consider producing a reproducable example with jsbin, jsfiddle or codepen. Your problem might be that punctuaciones is not an array for example

Comment: kindly add the puntuaciones array so it will be helpful to understand the problem

Comment: @JonathanM.Hethey - Not off-site, **on**-site with [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: This error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: If possible, sure, whatever works.

Comment: also please mention why it is downvoted, since new contributors may not be knowing how to post it. I am giving an upvote to give a chance +1

Comment: this array --> let puntuaciones = [
    { nombre: "Pablo", puntuacion: 180 },
    { nombre: "Javier", puntuacion: 270 },
    { nombre: "Raquel", puntuacion: 70 },
    { nombre: "Mario", puntuacion: 310 },
    { nombre: "Miriam", puntuacion: 90 },
    { nombre: "Laura", puntuacion: 210 },
];

Comment: when I run it it comes out undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one

```js
let puntuaciones = [{
  nombre: "Pablo",
  puntuacion: 180
}, {
  nombre: "Javier",
  puntuacion: 270
}, {
  nombre: "Raquel",
  puntuacion: 70
}, {
  nombre: "Mario",
  puntuacion: 310
}, {
  nombre: "Miriam",
  puntuacion: 90
}, {
  nombre: "Laura",
  puntuacion: 210
}, ];


function sortArrayHelper(array){
let sortedArray = puntuaciones.filter(item => item.puntuacion > 100).sort((a,b) => b.puntuacion - a.puntuacion)
return sortedArray
}

console.log(sortArrayHelper(puntuaciones))
```

Comment: This code 

let puntuaciones = [
    { nombre: "Pablo", puntuacion: 180 },
    { nombre: "Javier", puntuacion: 270 },
    { nombre: "Raquel", puntuacion: 70 },
    { nombre: "Mario", puntuacion: 310 },
    { nombre: "Miriam", puntuacion: 90 },
    { nombre: "Laura", puntuacion: 210 },
];

function recibirArray(puntuaciones){
    let array = puntuaciones.filter(item => item.puntuacion > 100);
    array.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseInt(b.puntuacion) - parseInt(a.puntuacion);
    });
}

console.log(recibirArray(puntuaciones));

Comment: so basically you want to filter the array who has puntuacion greater than 100 and need to sort it by descending. check now updated the answer

Comment: the problem was you were sorting but inside the function you need to return the array which you were not doing thats why it was comming as undefined .

Comment: @CraftianosHd happy coding :) Always remember in the question please add the sample snippet .. :) Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: And because days ago it worked for me? No understand, but thanks for solution DILEEP THOMAS